# Seat pitch / leg room on EVA Air SEA - TPE - KUL?

Tags: air-travel, seating

My wife and I are getting ready to fly to Kuala Lumpur for a family vacation.  We're contemplating flights on EVA Air, mostly because they're the cheapest for an economy flight.

I can't seem to figure out exactly which aircraft flies that route.  However I'm pretty sure it's a Boeing 777-300ER. I also haven't been able to figure out if this is one of their new-ish planes with 10 seats per row, or an older one with 9 (and hence wider-ish seats).  I think both flights (SEA-TPE & TPE-KUL) are on the same plane, but again I'm not sure.

As far as the seats themselves, I know that rows C, D, & H all have In Flight Entertainment boxes underneath the seats, so you don't want those.  Or at least I don't.  I'm 6'-2" tall, she's 5'-0" so she'll comfortably fit in nearly any seat.  She's very-very concerned that I'm going to be uncomfortable on the 18+ hour flight.  Even though I've had knee replacement surgery on both knees since the last time we flew back, I'm less so.  I've flown to SE Asia and back from the western US half a dozen times (never on EVA though), including Malaysian Airlines, Delta & United, all on either economy, or economy +.  As long as I can straighten my legs most of the way, I'm relatively sure I can endure the flights.  If I can determine which plane it is, I'm hopeful that I can use [SeatGuru](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13038/online-resources-for-airplane-seat-sizes) to learn what I want to know.

If not, what I'm really interested in is the seat pitch and leg room on that route?  [This closed question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/is-a-17-inch-wide-30-inch-pitch-seat-comfortable-for-a-long-haul-flight) only talks about seat pitch and leg room as general terms, I'm looking for specifics on a single route.

**Edit**:  After poking around on Google Flights, I was able to figure out what plane it is and using that on SeatGuru, I found:  [EVA Air Flight 25 (SEA-TPE)](https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Eva_Airways/Eva_Airways_Boeing_777-300ER.php?flightno=25&date=), which has 9 seats and average leg room of 31".  The next leg (TPE-KUL) is an Airbus A321 with an average of 31-32" and seat width of 17.7.  Pretty sure the return flight is just the reverse.

Answer (score 2):

If you search the flight on a search engine like [Kayak](http://kayak.com), it will tell you what type of plane they are planning to use. Then you can use SeatGuru to learn about the seats on that particular plane.